# Remove duplicates in two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Good day. Let me explain what am I doing right now:

I'm creating array from HTMLCollection (created via document.getElementsByClass())

```
var arry = Array.from(zlec);
```

It happens that each item in my array is span but its innerHTML is a path to file looking like this:

```
/PSO/Orders/2021/customer/ordernumber/grade/thickness/filenamewithextension
```

I wanted to extract customer and order number from each item so i created array inside of array:

```
for (j = 0; j < arry.length; j++) {
     arry[j] = arry[j].innerHTML.split("/");
}
```

And i could display it in some debug div using this clean line (in a loop ofcourse):

```
debug.innerHTML += "Customer: " + arry[j][4] + " - Order no.: " + arry[j][5] + "</br>";
```

Which brings beautiful result:

```
Customer: AAA - Order no.: 0332
Customer: AAA - Order no.: 0332
Customer: AAA - Order no.: 0332
Customer: AAA - Order no.: 0377
Customer: AAA - Order no.: 0377
Customer: BBB - Order no.: 0350
```

The question is how to remove duplicates in this results??

Are there possibility to use something like this pseudo code? How to call for those both items at the same time in sub array and compare to other pairs ?

```
For loop
{
   div.innerHTML = arry[j][4]&[j][5]
   if (arry[j+1][4]&[j+1][5] is equal to arry[j][4]&[j][5]) 
   {
      then do nothing and j++
   }
   else
   {
      div.innerHTML += arry[j+1][4]&[j+1][5]  and j++
   }
}
```

--------- Update ---------
Real-life data example (insinde HTMLCollection) censored about customers and numbers

```
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer W1/0324/1.4301/060/6_304_right.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0318/1.4301/060/2405-K1-10.0.0.02.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0318/1.4301/060/2405-K1-4.2.0.01.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0318/1.4301/060/2405-K1-13.0.0.00_p3.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0318/1.4301/060/2405-K1-1.0.0.01.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0318/1.4301/060/2405-K1-1.6.0.03.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0318/1.4301/060/2405-K1-1.7.0.02.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0322/1.4301/060/2405-K2-5.0.0.02.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0322/1.4301/060/2405-K2-6.0.0.01.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0322/1.4301/060/2405-K2-5.0.0.03.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0322/1.4301/060/2405-K2-7.0.0.01.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0322/1.4301/060/2405-K2-1.3.0.00_p1.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer O1/0394/1.4301/060/Curb_920.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E1/0374/1.4301/060/2400-K6-3.4.0.09.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer P1/0384/1.4301/060/HKL-049_3.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer P1/0384/1.4301/060/HKL-049_1.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer P1/0384/1.4301/060/HKL-049_2.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer P1/0384/1.4301/060/HKL-049_4.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E2/0382/1.4301/060/bracket_20.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E2/0382/1.4301/060/bracket_23.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E2/0382/1.4301/060/bracket_22.GEO 
/PSO/Orders/2021/Customer E2/0382/1.4301/060/bracket_21.GEO
```

Comment: Please provide your result array sample. This can be done.

Comment: Are you only interested in customer and order number? Nothing else from those paths?

Comment: Yes only customer paired with order number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary `Set` for getting unique values.

I would also use the `Array.from` callback argument to immediately map the HTML elements to their split `innerHTML` values, and then chain a `.map` to map those subarrays to the final display strings.

You can form the final HTML output by a simple `.join`:

```js
var debug = document.getElementById("dbg");
var zlec = document.getElementsByClassName("path");
var arry = Array.from(zlec, elem => 
    elem.innerHTML.split("/")
).map(([,,,,cust, ord]) =>
    `Customer: ${cust} - Order no.: ${ord}`
);

debug.innerHTML = [...new Set(arry)].join("<br>");
```

```html
<div class="path">/PSO/Orders/2021/Shell/12345678/grade/thickness/filenamewithextension</div>
<div class="path">/PSO/Orders/2021/NASA/829384751/grade/thickness/filenamewithextension</div>
<div class="path">/PSO/Orders/2021/Wallmart/927465822/grade/thickness/filenamewithextension</div>
<hr>
<div id="dbg"></div>
```

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for this masterpiece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method in array to return a new array of unique items

```
let result = arry.reduce((acc, i) => { 
                     if(acc.find(a => a[4]===i[4] && a[5]===i[5])) 
                           return acc; 

                      acc.push(i); 
                      return acc; }, 
             []); 

console.log(result);
```